# Using Javascript to read metadata from .bqy (Brio query file) file

Tags: javascript, brio

I have some .bqy (Brio query file) files I need to loop through them and read the metadata which is the OCE (database connection strings) and write them to an excel file.

Comment: did you get any solution for this, I have similar requirement

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a bqy doesn't know the information contained in the oce.  It pretty much only knows what's in the Connection Manager tool (thing you get when you press F11), even if that information is wrong and won't connect.

The official Oracle documentation says the data you're seeking might be in the `bqmeta0.ini` file, if it's provided by a third party vendor:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/ir_user/ch36s09s01.html

There are a lot of read only Properties under the `DataModel` object, which might be useful:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/ir_user/ch30s18.html
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/ir_user/ch30s17.html

Answer (score 0):

Desktop Hyperion - Create a BQY and use For loops to open each bqy then loop thru the object model.  You can write output to excel or access.  Something like this

```js
// Request Loop
for (var z = 1; z <= ActiveDocument.Sections[j].Requests.Count; z++) {
    // get_data
}
```

Comment: isn't `// get_data` the part they really want?